Migrating to Kotlin 2.0 causes error with KSP
After migrating to Kotlin 2.0, when I sync the project with the gradle files no issues arise. However, when I try to deploy to the device, I get the following error:
> Task :app:kspDebugKotlin FAILED
e: -api-version (2.0) cannot be greater than -language-version (1.9)

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.0-alpha08"
hiltAndroid = "2.51.1"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.51.1"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.21"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
composeNavigation = "2.8.0-beta01"
serialization = "1.6.3"
constraintlayout = "1.0.1"
ktor = "2.3.11"
logbackClassic = "1.5.6"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }
hilt-android-gradle-plugin = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "composeNavigation"}
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "serialization"}
androidx-constraintlayout = { module = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor"}
ktor-client-android = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-android", version.ref = "ktor"}
ktor-client-serialization = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization", version.ref = "ktor"}
ktor-client-logging = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging", version.ref = "ktor"}
logback-classic = { module = "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic", version.ref = "logbackClassic"}

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-ksp = {id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp"}
    kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin"}

build.gradle.kts (app/Module)
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinVersion

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mobi.ripple"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mobi.ripple"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_19.target
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.14"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        apiVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
        jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_19)
        languageVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)

    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    implementation(libs.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

    implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.serialization)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging)
    implementation(libs.logback.classic)
}

build.gradle.kts (Project)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.hilt.android.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

I tried adding different configurations but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

You need to enable KSP2 for k2.0 by adding
ksp.useKSP2=true

to gradle.properties
Even thought you are using ksp2 its still using 1.9 under the hood
source:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/12/ksp2-preview-kotlin-k2-standalone.html
